# CQRS/ES - do I understand It correctly?

Tags: events, cqrs

I would like to sum my knowledge about CQRS/ES. I started to read about this subject some time ago and because of I'm young developer I don't understand every aspect of that concept. I will try to describe my understanding of CQRS on some example flow. So defining general steps of that architecture we have following flow:

1. User makes request to our controller. In that controller method we create specified **Command** (for example **CreateOrder**) and pass it to **Handler**.
2. The global message bus (or handler) is responsible to routing the command to specified command handler. So here we pass command to **CreateOrderHandler**
3. In handler we create **Aggregate root** (in this case **OrderAggregate**) and we apply all events from **EventStore**. In EventStore we keep only events data related to specified aggregate (defined by global id). So after this step we have aggregate in current state.
4. When we have created aggregate we pass to It our command and in method we werify if command can be executed. If we can run this command we create **Event** (in this case **OrderCreated**).
5. If there is't any exception we save out Event in EventStore (I think simple to use NoSql DB and simple save events)
6. Now handler pass saved event to our **Denormalizer** class which is gateway to create **View Models**. So if denormalizer get some event it updates/creates all ViewModels in our app. We save ViewModel in separate DB.
7. User can query for updated view model.

So I this It is simplified version of my understanding of CQRS/ES. Please correct me on every layer. My questions here are:

In 4-th step we created aggregate should we save this aggregate in DB? To keep current state. Am I missing something here? We created aggregate only for checking possibility to create event?

Should I have Entities? If I am correct in 5-th step I can update aggregate entities and use them in my view models. I have the biggest confusion here.

Thanks for all answers ;)

Comment: I read only about this topic, but afaik. you can save the actual aggregate with "snapshot"s, so you don't have to build it always from zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In 4-th step we created aggregate should we save this aggregate in DB?
>   To keep current state. Am I missing something here? We created
>   aggregate only for checking possibility to create event?

If you use an EventStore,the ES itself keeps the state of your aggregates. You talk about "create" aggregate in command-handler, but generally it's better to say that in command-handlers the aggregates are re-hydrated from ES.

An Aggregate uses the commands (or their data) and raises (domain) events that are applied in the ES to trace the aggregate's state changes and, the same events are handled by event handlers (like denormalizer).

In the flow described usually I've a command validation step before step 3.
Anyway, some time ago I tried to depict the [components of a typical CQRS/ES flow](http://williamverdolini.github.io/2014/08/11/cqrses-architecture/); there are several on web, but maybe it could be useful

Answer (score 0):

An aggregates state is derived from the past events applied to it. So you don't need to store it's state as it is derived from the event stream. Having said that you may want to create snapshots to avoid a very long event history. Before designing a snap shotting system, it's worth testing how quick re-applying a list  of previous events is.

When you issue a command to an aggregate it handles it in 2 stages. The first stage essentially checks it can run. If so it builds up the event or events to represent the change before applying them to it's self. Key here is that the production of events can and often does require the application of domain logic. In other words it's not just an event producer.

If you find it helpful I have a more detail overview of a typical CQRS application on my blog. You can find it here: [CQRS – A Step-by-Step Guide to the Flow of a typical Application](http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/10/02/cqrs-step-step-guide-flow-typical-application/)